# Pandas dataframe sum two rows if they meet two different requirements

Tags: python, pandas, sum, rows

I have the following table.

```
| product | check | check1 | type | amount |
|---------|-------|--------|------|--------|
| A       | 1     | a      | c    | -10    |
| A       | 1     | a      | p    | 20     |
| B       | 2     | b      | c    | 20     |
| B       | 2     | b      | p    | 20     |
| C       | 3     | c      | c    | -10    |
| D       | 4     | d      | p    | 15     |
| D       | 4     | d      | c    | -15    |
```

I want to sum the amount for the rows where the first three columns are equal and one row in the 'type' columns contains 'C' and the other row a 'P' then also where 'type' = 'C' amount should be negative and when 'type' = 'P' the amount should be positive, otherwise they should not be summed. if they are summed the if the 'amount' is negative, 'type' should be 'c' otherwise 'p'.see required output below:

```
| product | check | check1 | type | amount |
|---------|-------|--------|------|--------|
| A       | 1     | a      | p    | 10     |
| B       | 2     | b      | c    | 20     |
| B       | 2     | b      | p    | 20     |
| C       | 3     | c      | c    | -10    |
| D       | 4     | d      | p    | 0      |
```

i have tried `group.by` on the first three columns and then apply a lambda function;

```
df = df.groupby(['product', 'check', 'check1']).apply(lambda x, y : x + y, x.loc[(x['type']=='c')], y.loc[(y['type']=='p')], 'amount')
```

This gives a NameError where 'x' is not defined. I am also not sure if this is the right way to go, so if you have any tips please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for this, maybe not efficient but it works!

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for product in df['product'].unique():
    for check in df[df['product'] == product].check.unique():
        for check1 in df[(df['product'] == product) & (df.check == check)].check1.unique():
            tmp = df[(df['product'] == product) & (df.check == check) & (df.check1 == check1)]
            if len(tmp[((tmp.type == 'c') & (tmp.amount < 0)) | ((tmp.type == 'p') & (tmp.amount > 0))]) != 2:
                new_df = new_df.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)
            else:
                amount = tmp.sum()['amount']
                type = 'c' if amount < 0 else 'p'                
                elt = {
                    'product': product,
                    'check': check,
                    'check1': check1,
                    'type': type,
                    'amount': amount
                }
                new_df = new_df.append(pd.Series(elt), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, maybe not the most efficient way but i am already very happy that this works, have been struggling with it for days!